# .map cannot be used, but I have set an empty array initially

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this tricky question but dunno how to solve it. I tried to .map to print out some data today from the recipe which I have set as an empty array initially. However, an error popped up and it said, `recipe.map is not a function`, so I went to `console.log (typeof ....` and `console.log` lots of things. I found out

```
const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState([]);
```

so when I have objects in the recipe, I can apply `.map` to print out whatever the content is in it.

However when there is one object in the recipe, or there is one thing I want to print out from the recipe, the object would not be put in the array! It will just show up as an object and then I cannot apply .map on it since `.map` can only be applied on an array but I have actually set it to an empty array in the first place.

I have also tried

```
const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState([{}]);

const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState([{},{}]);
```

but none of these work. I expected outcome is there are multiple recipes in the list, and when I clicked into one of them, users will be redirected to the specific recipe.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const SingleRecipe = () => {
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState([]);
  const { recipeID } = useParams(); //useParams needs curly bracket and no need  []
  console.log(typeof recipe);
  console.log("this is recipeID" + recipeID);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3001/recipe/detail/${recipeID}`)
      .then((response) => {
       
        setRecipe(response.data);
        console.log("this is useEffect in SingleRecipe..." + response.data);
       
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response) alert(JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="recipeSession">
      <h1 className="recipeSessionHeader">Recipe</h1>
      <div className="recipesContainer">
        <div className="recipes">
          <ul className="recipeList">
            {recipe.map((singleRecipe) => (
              <li key={singleRecipe._id}>
                <div className="recipeName">
                  <h2 className="recipeNameHeader">{singleRecipe.name}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="recipePhoto">
                  <img src={singleRecipe.imageUrl} alt={singleRecipe.name} />
                </div>
                <div className="recipeIngredients">
                  <p>{singleRecipe.ingredient}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="recipeInstruction">
                  <p>{singleRecipe.instruction}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="recipeCookingTime">
                  <p> Cooking Time: {singleRecipe.cookingTime}(minutes)</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleRecipe;
```

Comment: if `response.data` is an object u may have to set state like `setRecipe([...recipe,response.data])`

Comment: OMG, never thought of it this way!!!!!!!
thank you so much for you help!!!!!!

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be confusion about whether this component should render one or many recipes.

If you intended this to be a "detail" view that shows a single recipe rather than an array of recipes as your component name, `fetch` call, `const { recipeID } = useParams();` and `recipe` (singular) variable name indicate, don't use arrays or `.map` at all.

```js
const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState(null);
```

In your render, change `singleRecipe` to `recipe` (or rename state to `const [singleRecipse, setSingleRecipe] = useState(null)`) and conditionally render it, removing the `<ul>`:

```js
recipe ? (
  <div>{/* render the recipe */}</div>
) : (
  <div>Loading recipe...</div>
)
```

There's no need for the `<ul>` and `<li>` for a single item.

---

On the other hand, if you intended to use this component to list multiple recipes, change your fetch to

```js
.get(`http://localhost:3001/recipe`)
```

or

```js
.get(`http://localhost:3001/recipes`)
```

which presumably returns an array of recipes which you can then overwrite the state with:

```js
setRecipes(response.data);
```

Notice I've pluralized `recipes` since it's an array, keeping the intent clear.

Remove `const { recipeID } = useParams();` which is misleading and no longer used if your intent is to render multiple recipes. Rename the component to `Recipes` or `AllRecipes`.

You can use `null` or `[]` as the default and conditionally render a loading message or an empty array message. For example:

```js
// ....

if (!recipes) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
else if (recipes.length === 0) {
  return <div>No recipes yet</div>;
}

return (
  <ul>
    {recipes.map(e => (
      <li key={e._id}>
        {e.name}
        {/* render other relevant stuff ... */}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
// ...
```

Comment: thanks for editing the post for me and the opinions

Comment: I have read this usage before , 
"setRecipes(prev => [...prev, ...response.data]);"

but what is the difference in it 

comparing to .map to print out multiple recipes

Comment: really detailed comment, really appreciate for your help. I now understand how to code in a better way

Comment: `.map` is being used to transform plain JS objects into JSX. `setRecipes` is used to add recipes to the array. Looking at it again, it can be simplified to `setRecipes(repsonse.data)`. The syntax you quoted is only if you're merging two arrays, like a "fetch more recipes" infinite scroller type scenario, but that doesn't apply here. Updated my answer. I assume `response.data` is an array if you remove the `/detail/${recipeId}` part. Otherwise, it'd be `setRecipe(prev => [...prev, response.data])` to add a single item to an existing array, probably also not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the state with the API response instead of pushing the response to the state array.

Try changing `setRecipe(response.data)` to `setRecipe(prev => [...prev, response.data])`. This will maintain an array data type in state.

See [this](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) page on the React docs for more details